# Saving list of strings to csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, function, csv, save, export-to-csv

I am collecting data on a usb device and am getting 2 sets of data as a variable which contains 200 data points as comma-separated strings. How can I save these variables as csv files on my computer then? Ideally, I think I would like to do this in a function because I would like to efficiently repeat this for a lot of data sets, without overriding them.

Here is my current code:

```
freq = instr.ask("FREQ:DATA?")
data = instr.ask("CALC:DATA:FDATa?")

#convert freq and data to strings comma-separated and then arrays of floats
datalist=data.split(',')
dataarray=np.array(datalist)
datafloat=dataarray.astype(np.float)

freqlist=freq.split(',')
freqarray=np.array(freqlist)
freqfloat=freqarray.astype(np.float)

#save data
output = np.column_stack((freqfloat, datafloat))
with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in output:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

So after this is where I would like to create a save data function which I can call and repeat for later data sets. Any help is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module from the Python standard library to write csv files.

To generate a new file every time you save data, you can generate a file name with a number. Increment the number until the file does not exist yet. Here is a function that will save data consecutively to `prefix_1.csv`, `prefix_2.csv`, and so on:

```
import csv
import os

def save_csv(file_prefix, data):
    i = 1
    file_name = file_prefix + '_' + str(i) + '.csv'
    while os.path.isfile(file_name):
        i = i + 1
        file_name = file_prefix + '_' + str(i) + '.csv'

    with open(file_name, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)

# Save output to file data_x.csv
output = np.column_stack((freqfloat, datafloat))
save_csv('data', output)
```

Comment: I ended up using `np.savetxt` to solve my problem, but this works too--thank you! Do you have any advice on creating a function here so that I can save multiple data sets and not override anything (i.e. give them unique names without having to go back into the program and change it myself)? (rest of code added to question)

Comment: Changed to use `csv.writer`

Comment: I enhanced the answer to illustrate how the data can be saved to a new file on every call.

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, can you maybe give me an example of how you would call this then? Sorry, I'm very unfamiliar with how functions work.

Comment: I added a sample call.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting an error `name 'output' is not defined`. I'm wondering if I am supposed to delete my `output=np.column_stack` line that is in my code, and if you are interchanging `output` and `data`?

Comment: No, your line where you define the 'output' variable is required of course. I added it to my example. The value of the 'output' variable in the call is assigned to the local variable 'data' inside the function. They don't need to have the same name.

Comment: Got it, simple fix. Thanks for being patient!